# Why do I have to pass several arguments to the callback-function of the forEach-method to perform styling on dom elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Hey my following code looks like this (and it works):

```
allParagraphs.forEach((p, i) => {
    if(i == 0){
        p.style.fontSize = '100px';
    }else if(i == 1){
        p.style.fontSize = '10px';
    }else if(i == 2){
        p.style.fontSize = '50px';
    }else if(i == 3){
        p.style.fontSize = '25px';
    }
})
```

But I am wondering why the following two would not work?:

1.

```
allParagraphs.forEach((p, i) => {
    if(i == 0){
        i.style.fontSize = '100px';
    }else if(i == 1){
        i.style.fontSize = '10px';
    }else if(i == 2){
        i.style.fontSize = '50px';
    }else if(i == 3){
        i.style.fontSize = '25px';
    }
})
```

2. 

```
allParagraphs.forEach((p, i) => {
    if(p == 0){
        i.style.fontSize = '100px';
    }else if(p == 1){
        i.style.fontSize = '10px';
    }else if(p == 2){
        i.style.fontSize = '50px';
    }else if(p == 3){
        i.style.fontSize = '25px';
    }
})
```

I thought that the arguments passed to the callback are just abstractions for the arrays index, so that elements get called by there index? But if that was true, at least the second example should work right?
Iam just learning to code. Sorry if that question is stupid

Comment: Is #1 missing some code?

Comment: Oh sorry id did not copy it properly in my file it is correct.

Comment: Because the parameters for the callback on [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) are `element, index, array` (you don't have to include them all)... so in your working example `p` is the element and `i` is the index

Comment: You dont need to pass arguments if you dont need them. But in this case you need them. `Array.forEach` callback arguments are `element, index, array`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 5):

The way that `.forEach` works is it will step through an array and call your function for every element of that array. When your function gets called, three things get passed in:

1. The element of the array that we're working on right now
2. The index at which that element is found
3. The entire array

These are passed in as the first, second, and third arguments to the function. You can name them however you like, but first is always the element, second is always the index, and third is always the array. And it's fine to leave off the later arguments if you don't need them (eg, you didn't have a third argument for the array, which is very common)

So in this code:

```
allParagraphs.forEach((p, i) => {
```

`p` is the element of the array (the paragraph), and `i` is the index (a number). Any code that needs the index must interact with `i` (eg, `if(i == 0){`), and any code that needs the element must interact with `p` (eg, `p.style.fontSize = '100px';`).

Doing something like `i.style.fontSize = '10px';` won't work, because `i` is just a number and doesn't have a style property. And `if(p == 0){` won't work because `p` is not a number, and thus not zero.